# Measurements of the volume and surface resistivities of electrical insulating materials

Tags: resistance, resistivity

According to [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3340611_Changes_proposed_for_the_IEC_60093_Standard_concerning_measurements_of_the_volume_and_surface_resistivities_of_electrical_insulating_materials) in table 1 there are values of volume resistivity measured with application of electrodes made of conducting rubber ρvr and evaporated silver ρvs.

[image]

Under table 1 is note: 
"Results     of     resistivity     measurements     obtained     with     application  of  electrodes  made  of  conducting  rubber  are  always higher (few tents-few hundreds %) in comparison to that obtained for metallic electrodes"

My question is why resistivity   measurements of conducting  rubber electrodes are always higher than electrodes  made  of metallic electrodes?

Comment: Are you asking, essentially, why rubber-based things are more resistive (less conductive) than metal-based things?

Comment: @JYelton, I agree that is the main question. Rubber does naturally have less free valence electrons, and is thus less conductive (more resistive). However, there may be applications when a rubber probe is desirable; such as to maintain surface smoothness/integrity and to limit metal on metal contact.

Comment: No, electrodes in table 1 are used as a measurement instruments. With these electrodes and other stuff you can measure resistance, resistivity etc. of a material like in table 1 Polylac ABC, Polyamide etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't attempt to explain it in the paper, as you know. I would think (aka guess) it has something to do with the interface of the electrode and the solid. A **vacuum-deposited silver** electrode is in intimate atomic-level contact with all the surface details of the material, whereas a conductive rubber is probably only touching at microscopic high points, despite the apparent compliance of the rubber- so the apparent conductivity appears to be lower (higher resistance).

As to whether reading high by 50-300% is a big deal, my reference data for bulk resistivity of insulators tends to give numbers within pretty wide range- for example polycarbonate 
has a stated resistivity in the range of  \$10^{12} \$~\$ 10^{14}\Omega\text{-m}\$, which is 100:1 not 3:1.

Comment: Yes you have right opinion. According to this [original article](https://www.dbc.wroc.pl/Content/1172/lisowski_pomiary_rezystywnosci.pdf) in Polish language. In page 38 picture 4.2.2 is shown how "the air gap between the electrode and the tested material causes a particularly large inaccuracy in the measurement when the tested material has a small thickness." Page 79:"Measuring electrode covered with conductive rubber, while the ring, which is a voltage electrode, has a trapezoidal end. Because it adheres inaccurately to the ideally flat sample, they are formed significant measurement errors."